# Antibonding, non-bonding or bonding hybridization

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, band-structure, solid-state-physics, atoms-in-molecules

In case of CsSnI3 and CsGeI3 perovskites, the strong antibonding hybridization of Sn-s/Ge-s state with I-p state lies near to VBM of these materials. In this informative [paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/ta/c6ta04685a) (P.No.13853, 14th line), it is said that this makes it easier to create holes. Can anyone please help me understand why this is so and how to identify from band-structure/PDOS whether orbitals are hybridized antibondingly/non-bondingly/bondingly? How do I know whether antibonding hybridization is near or far from VBM?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?